# Problems with dyld, can not use even ls or mkdir

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, dyld

In terminal, while typing `ls`, I'm getting messages like:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
>
> Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ls
>
> Reason: image not found
>
> Trace/BPT trap: 5"

The same is for almost all other commands (also `mkdir`).

Brew is not installed, but all fixes of this problem `/usr/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib`  which I found, use brew somehow.

Do you have any suggestions?

ANSWER: I modified PATH as it was suggested, now I can manage the problems since standart bash commands are unlocked.

Comment: Sounds like you have a very modified operating system on your Macintosh.  If you didn't mean for this to be the case, you might need to reinstall MacOS to fix any unexpected corruption.

Comment: Why not use that standard `/bin/ls`? It seems that you have a problem with your local installs. Modify your path to launch standard commands instead.

Comment: to Jean-Baptiste Yunès: thanks, it works.